Problem with mysql2 installation on Sonoma MacOS
I'm having trouble with my mysql2 installation on Sonoma 14.3.1.
I have already installed MySQL via brew, as well as openssl (OpenSSL 3.3.0 9 Apr 2024) and zstd (Zstandard CLI 64-bit v1.5.6) libraries.
X-code also installed (version: 15.3.0.0.1.1708646388). But when I try to install mysql2, I end up with an error and have no idea, how to fix it.
I type in the command:
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/lib --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/bin/mysql_config --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/include 

The error message is the following:
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_gc_mark_movable()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... no
-----
Cannot find library dir(s) /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/4e1473ee-9f66-11ee-8daf-cedaeb4cabe2/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.3.Internal.sdk/usr/local/libressl-by-deployment-target/13.0/lib
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers. 

As far as I can see, there's something wrong with Xcode libressl library folder or its headers.
Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

I was facing similar issue installing & bundling gem mysql2 on my Sonoma M3 Apple Silicon Mac and what resolved it for me was adding the right ruby path to the .zshrc):
On running similar command:
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-lib=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/lib --with-mysql-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1 --with-mysql-config=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/bin/mysql_config --with-mysql-include=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/include ) 

I was seeing the following message:
This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.5.6
<internal:/Users/USERABC/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in 
`require': linked to incompatible 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/libruby.2.6.dylib - /Users/USERABC/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0@proctorserv/gems/date-3.3.4/lib/date_core.bundle
(LoadError)

and bundling would fail for me with the same error message as yours:
extconf failed, exit code 1

Did you notice the same response ^ on gem install i.e. "linked to incompatible ... bundle [LoadError]" ? Or was your gem installed properly?
If it was use of System Ruby 2.6.0 by Xcode that is the issue for you, it may be resolved similarly i.e. exporting a newer version of ruby path. Hope this helps.
